# Why does scipys stats.bernoulli.rvs yields an array with dtype int32?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am wondering why `scipy`s random variable class `stats.bernoulli` yields ndarrays with dtype `int32` as samples:

```
 > stats.bernoulli.rvs(0.3, size=10)
 array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 > stats.bernoulli.rvs(0.3, size=10).dtype
 dtype('int32')
```

Using 32-Bit-Integer values for binary results seems to be extremely inefficient. I would have expected a dtype of `np.bool` or `np.int8`.

Does anyone know the reason for the decision to generate `int32` arrays as samples?

**Remark**: I am working with big (10^8) samples. Strangely, a conversion to `int8` does not give me a any better performance, neither with creating the array nor with calculating function over the array. Maybe because my CPU can just handly 32-bit / 64-bit chunks...

Comment: It's probably using whatever `int` data-type `numpy` defaults to. This will depend on your system. On most *nix flavors, I think you'll get 64-bit ints for 64 bit architectures, and 32-bit ints for 32-bit architectures. I believe on Windows, the default is 32 regardless of architecture. On my Mac laptop, 64-bit, I'm getting 64-bit `int`. so whatever `np.int_` returns.

Answer (score 1):

On my system it's `int64`, so yeah, it's just a default integer size. Why not `bool` you say. In the source code it uses `scipy.hypergeom` which returns integers.
The only way I can think of is to pre-initialize your output arrays with `dtype=np.bool`, if you can. Then although you will still waste some memory on generation of `stats.bernoulli.rvs`, you can clear it up right after.